# Inject a render tag placed in the head into body on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

In a shopify project i have a snippet that renders some HTML, CSS, and a small bit of JS (about 50 lines) thats all located in that snippet file.

If i place this snippet in the head tag it doesn't affect performance. (45 or so on mobile) BUT placing a render snippet in the head tag causes all the head tags code to get injected into the body when you look at the dev tools.

If i place the render snippet before the closing body tag there is a significant performance drop. (30 or so on mobile)

Im not sure a workaround for this ? im thinking of trying to do something like this. Where the render snippet would stay in the head but get injected into the body on page load or something and seeing if that prevents the devtools from putting all the head code into the body while also not affecting performance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'http://yourdomian.com/your_script.js');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Comment: you need to check the code, and why it down the performance after adding to the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scroll jQuery event to load the script, this will not affect the site speed.

The script is automatically added when you perform the first scroll.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).one("scroll", function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('src', 'http://yourdomian.com/your_script.js');
  script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
});
</script>
```